# Block any comments on all my Facebook posts (public, future and past)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a page on Facebook, where I often place public posts. I don't want anyone being able to "answer" comments to the posts. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, as of now it is not possible. But what you think you can give your [feedback to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499).